# Delete Black Line in Search Results TableView

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

Experts,

This is something specific to Xamarin.iOS & iOS 11.  I see an extra black line in my search results table view controller.  iOS 9 & 10, the black line is not there and looking fine.  Wondering if anyone else is seeing this, and a potential fix for it. See screenshot.

[image: sea]

Answer (score 2):

After some playing around I found out that there is a new property new to iOS 11 that pads SearchResultsTableView.  This worked for me below:

`searchDisplayController.SearchResultsTableView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.Never;`